# Accessing BSP application through URL

Tags: sap-bsp

I have created a bsp application. For accessing this application i am facing problems. And regarding URL i have some doubt.

**Doubt 1:**-  http://xyz.abc.com:8000/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/ns/mt_mwm/issuesto.html
                in this url what is (bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)   this.

**Problem:** wnen i am maving TP development to quality this code ( (bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==) ) got changed. and from quality to production again got changed.my queastion how to make it dynamic. from where i can get it.??

I am following this link https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp1/helpdata/en/ca/f8b53a364e0e5fe10000000a11405a/content.htm

Answer (score 2):

What you see is added by the SAP server for session handling! You don't have to worry about it, it will be added automatically. If you want to bookmark a link to your app then just remove this **(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)**. Also, never use this hard coded in your code! For more information see [this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_dm40/helpdata/en/1e/15520141459e43a19accf2fb02075f/content.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a static link, use this notation: `http://xyz.abc.com:8000/sap(====)/bc/bsp/ns/mt_mwm/issuesto.html`